# How to input individual fields of data from Excel spreadsheet and scraping each of the results?

Tags: r

Could someone point me in the right correction of how I would create a script that automatically input each individual fields of a column from an Excel spreadhseet into the search bar, scrape the results, and then continue doing so for each of the fields in the same column?

site:

```
https://www.aapc.com/icd-10/codes/
```

sample data from spreadsheet:

```
    c("001", "001.0", "001.1", "001.9", "001-009", "002", "002.0", 
"002.1", "002.2", "002.3")
```

Expected output from the first three codes above:

```
Result not found for the provided ICD-9 Code
A00.0   Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae  gem
A00.1   Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor gem
```

Answer (score 0):

As you described, it takes 3 steps, and you need to know the packages you can use for each one.

1. Read data from excel: `readxl`,`openxlsx`,`XLConnect`
2. Enter the value in search engine and scrape results.: `httr`,`rvest`,`RSelenium`
3. Iterate two steps above

It's not a simple process if you don't know these packages or related technology, especially for web scraping. You need to learn some HTML and at least know what is CSS and how to use CSS Selectors.